# Return a 1D numpy array of a specific index from an axis in 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

This should be trivial but I'm not finding the correct way to accomplish it. I have a 2D array with shape `(5, 5527)` I have an an array of indices with the lowest value for the arguments in the first axis with shape `(5527,)`

How can I flatten my `(5,5527)` array into a 1D array by only using the values at the index specified by the index array?

I thought [np.take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) would accomplish this but it does not. It outputs an array with shape `(5527,5527)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close: [np.take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html)

Comment: Ah, I needed to add a dimension to the indices for that one to work. Okay thanks.